# Requring static class setter to be called before constructor, bad design?

Tags: design, static-methods, constructors

I have a class, say `Foo,` and every instance of Foo will need and contain the same List object, `myList.`

Since every class instance will share the same List Object, I thought it would be good to make `myList` static and use a static function to set `myList` before the constructor is called.

I was wondering if this was bad, because this requires the setter to be called before the constructor? If the person doesn't, the program will crash. Alternative way would be passing `myList` every time.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design choice, but to be sure and to give you an alternative, we'd need to know more about your intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requiring a certain method to be called *before* another is called [*Sequential Coupling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling), and is often considered to be an antipattern. Take for example this code generator:

```
cg.enterScope();
... // add operations inside this scope
cg.leaveScope();
```

Here, `leaveScope` always has to be called after `enterScope`, else incorrect code is emitted. This can be trivially refactored to use a `Scope` type:

```
Scope(scoped_operations).generate_code(cg);
```

Your case is trickier, as you want to lazily initialize a static member before any instances of that class are created. I guess this will look like

```
TheClass.initialize();
var instance = new TheClass();  // first use
```

The first step is to make `initialize` threadsafe. Then, it has to record whether it has already run. If so, any future calls simply short circuit:

```
static bool is_initialized = false;

static synchronized void initialize() {
  if (is_initialized) return;
  ...; // normal initialization
  is_initialized = true;
}
```

Now we can do this call inside the constructor to make sure the class is always initialized before other code runs:

```
TheClass(...) {
  if (!is_initialized) initialize(); // try to avoid call to synchronized method
  ...;
}
```

---

If the initialization doesn't have to happen lazily, various simpler solutions can be used. (In this context, lazy initialization means that initialization is only ever performed if an instance is created). For something as *cheap* as creating a List object, you will probably want to initialize it regardless of any objects created. Different languages have different mechanisms, e.g.

```
// Java, C#
static List<Foo> myList = new List<Foo>();

// Java: static initializer block
static {
  myList = new List<Foo>();
}
```

---

If the initialization value is not known at compile time, but is rather provided by a user, this gets complicated again. In some languages you can parameterize classes themselves, e.g. `TheClass = new TheMetaClass(42); instance = new TheClass()`. In languages lacking a Metaobject Protocol, the *Factory Pattern* can be used instead: `factory = new TheClassFactory(42); instance = factory.create()`. This looks similar to the sequentially coupled example at the beginning, but with a factory the type system can guarantee that initialization has happened before an instance is created.

Comment: I think he meant the calling code would call the static `initialize()` only once, and not *every* time before we call the constructor. In other words, the check `if (is_initialized) return;` may not be needed.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it's bad.**

Consider the alternative where you always pass in the list in constructor; you can still make each object receive the same list, e.g. by storing the list in the factory for the object, and passing it on new.

And since the class advertises that it needs a list instance by only offering a constructor that takes this instance, the user knows he's passing in null if he's not using the factory. This is much more obvious than requiring to call a static function.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you can create the list instance in the static constructor implicitly:

```
static List<int> myList = new List<int>();

public Foo()
{
   myList.Add(42); // note: not thread safe!!!
}
```

or explicitly:

```
static List<int> myList;

static Foo()
{
   myList = new List<int>();    
}

public Foo()
{
   myList.Add(42); // note: not thread safe!!!
}
```

This is better than setting it independently for a number of reasons, but mostly:

- static constructors only execute once (useful in multithreaded contexts)
- static constructors are run before anything else, so you can assume that the field is always initialized

More in general, it is good practice to make a class "ready to use" in the constructor, and static members in the static constructor. This prevents having an instance with uninitialized fields.

Requiring a particular order of calls is possibly an anti-pattern known as [Sequential Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) and I would avoid doing that unless necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By having global state you effectively implemented a `FooFactory` as a singleton (well, using `static` fields, but the effect is the same).

How about making the factory part explicit and getting rid of the singleton part (as singleton  is quite untestable, due to the action-at-a-distance problem):

```
public class FooFactory {
  private List myList;
  public FooFactory(List myList) {
    // ideally probably create an immutable copy of it
    this.myList = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(myList));
    // ensure that myList has all the required characteristics
    if (this.myList.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't build a FooFactory with an empty myList");
    }
  }

  public Foo newFoo() {
    return new Foo(myList);
  }
}
```

This, together with a package-private `Foo` constructor (so that noone can go the direct, dangerous route) ensures that only proper `Foo` objects will be created.

- no action-at-a-distance, you always explicitly reference the `FooFactory` that contains the state
- no accidentally changing someone elses `FooFactory` (since it's immutable)
- you can't accidentally create a broken `Foo` object

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to use the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

A real world example would be if a worker has a task to do and that task requires the use of a shared list why should the manager have to tell the worker what list to use when his/her task already knows which list is needed?

Make the `myList` class a singleton then in the constructor of the `Foo` class have it get a pointer to the one instance of the `myList` object.

```
Class myList
{
  static myList * get_instance()
  {
    static myList m_instance;
    return &m_instance;
  }
};

Class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    myList * m_list = MyList::get_instance();
  }
};
```

This solution is the simplest for the requirements stated because it does not required the code creating the object to even care about the shared list but simply creates the Foo object.

Comment: You have provided "how" but you have not provided a "why."  For programmers, the _why_ is much more important as it makes the answer more applicable to a wider variety of cases.

Comment: @GlenH7, Because it just makes sense to me. 

If there is a worker that has a task to do and that task requires the use of a shared list why should the manager have to tell the worker what list to use when his task already knows which list is needed?

This also is the simplest solution to the OP’s requirements. The other solutions require extra code to get and pass the pointer to a new Foo object each and every time on is instantiated. Whereas my solutions does not required the code creating the object to even care about the shared list but simply creates the Foo object.

Comment: That would be useful information to [edit] into your answer.